# SSIS + project level connection manager + ExecuteOutOfProcess = failing package

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

We have a setup common among a few of our packages where we have a main parent package which then fires off a number of child packages in parallel.

For some of these the amount of memory used risks getting out of memory errors if they are run with ExecuteOutOfProcess set to false and so we changed these to be ExecuteOutOfProcess = true.  This all worked fine within BIDS with package level connection managers.

We are currently trying to move to project level connection managers with SSIS 2012.  Having deployed the project to the server we are finding the packages execute ok with ExecuteOutOfProcess set to false (for smaller amounts of data), but if we try to run them out of process the child packages are getting validation errors when they try to access tables via the project level (OLEDB) connection manager.

Any ideas as to what is causing the error to occur only when out of process?

Comment: Are you using Package Parent Variables to pass any connection info? Are you using Environments and References? Or just one static value for the connection string? Basically, can you give a bit more detail about how your connection managers are set up?

Comment: It is just a straight forward single connection manager with a static connection string to a SQL Server 2012 database, windows authentication.   Integration services is running as a user that has access to the database, and the user executing the parent package also has permissions to access that database.